# How to create onKernelRequest event listener in laravel

Tags: laravel, symfony, event-listener

I want to create `onKernelRequest` event listener in laravel so how can do that. i want to handle some code on every request using any listener.
In symfony i have created this type of listener something like this

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class RequestListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            // don't do anything if it's not the master request
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

So finally in laravel how can i do this type of listener